# Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'build\app' imported from build\server.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm using typescript in a node project.
To make things simple and clear, the project stucture is like this:

```
    --src
      |-- server.ts
      |-- app.ts
    --build
      |-- server.js
      |-- app.js
```

server.ts:

```
import { app } from "./app";

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listens on 127.0.0.1:${port}`);
});
```

app.ts:

```
import express, { Express } from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import { routes } from "./routes/index";

const app: Express = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use("/", routes);

export {
  app,
};
```

tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6", 
    "module": "es2015",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "start": "nodemon build/server",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "type": "module",
.
.
.
```

I execute `npm run build`  then I run  `npm start`, I got this error:

```
internal/process/esm_loader.js:74
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\x\Desktop\projects\done_list\build\app' imported from C:\Users\x\Desktop\projects\done_list\build\server.js
    at finalizeResolution (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:270:11)
    at moduleResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:667:10)
    at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:778:11)
    at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:85:40)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:229:28)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:51:40)
    at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:50:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

How can I fix that?

**OS: windows 10**

**Node: 14.9.0**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue by removing `"type": "module"` from package.json and updating the tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6", 
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello pal! This doesn't answer the crux of the question.